# How to add AWS SES (Simple Email Service) to .net 6 program.cs

Tags: c#, amazon-ses, .net-6.0

I need to send emails in .net 6 using Amazon SES.

In .net 5 and before you needed to add this to startup.cs

```
    // Amazon SES
    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleEmailService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, CSharpAwsSesServiceHelper.EmailService.AwsEmailService>();
    services.Configure<AwsEmailServiceOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AwsEmailServiceOptions)))
        .AddSingleton(x => x.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AwsEmailServiceOptions>>().Value);
```

In .net 6 there is no Startup.cs, it has been replaced and simplified in program.cs.

However, there's no Configuration object by default in program.cs like there is in Startup.cs, and this doesn't work (error 'Configuration does not contain GetAWSOptions())

I've searched for a sample project or guidance, eg
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-6-on-aws/

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-net-guides/tree/master/RuntimeSupport/dotnet6

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/11/28/net-core-c-aws-ses-send-email-via-smtp-with-aws-simple-email-service

But can't find the .net 6 version of this code.

Anybody know what best practice is here / how to make this work?

Thanks.

UPDATE

I've copied all using statements from Startup.cs to Program.cs - this is not the problem.

I then copied the service builder across (changing services. to builder.Services.) I get the error listed above due to the lack of a Configuration object in program.cs.

Comment: "this doesn't work" what is "this"? The most obvious solution is to add the missing `using` statement

Comment: You must be configuring services in Program.cs, right? It's the same service builder as you would have in Startup.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify these points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fugured it out - you just need to add builder. to the start of Configuration - ie

```
// Amazon SES
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleEmailService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, CSharpAwsSesServiceHelper.EmailService.AwsEmailService>();
builder.Services.Configure<AwsEmailServiceOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AwsEmailServiceOptions)))
    .AddSingleton(x => x.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AwsEmailServiceOptions>>().Value);
```